# Coldfusion Jquery Ajax call - 500 error

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I know this subject has been beaten to death.  But I'm not able to resolve it from my research.  I'm using CF 9 and Jquery 1.8.  I tried to use a cfc for the ajax call and got the 500 error.  I changed it to a cfm and have turned the url path inside out.  I have a lot of other code that doesn't provide a path (default to the current folder).  Dev tools gives me the following response;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can post the page directly from the browser and it executes perfectly. No 500 error and the data is updated to the DB.  There are no log entries that I can find on the server.
The code snippet is;

```
$('##clnoteformdivedit').on('click', function() {
                var thisuserid = $(this).parent().find('##ClIndNoteIndivnum').val();
                var thisindivnote = $(this).parent().find('##indNote').val();
                alert(thisuserid + '--' + thisindivnote);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "actUpdateClIndivNote.cfm",
                    data: 'calllistID=' + <cfoutput>#val(attributes.callListId)#</cfoutput> + '&userid=' + thisuserid + '&IndivNote' + thisindivnote,
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // show error
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function(response1, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('##clnoteformdivedit').hide();
                        $('##clnoteformdivdisplay').show();
                    }
                });
            });
```

actUpdateClIndivNote.cfm code;

```
<cfset attributes.suppresslayout2 = "true">
<cfquery datasource="#request.dsn#" name="updateCLnotes" >
            update call_lists_users
            set notes = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" value="#url.IndivNote#">
            WHERE   UsersID = <cfqueryparam value="#val(url.userid)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
                and CallListsId = <cfqueryparam value="#val(listfirst(url.callListId))#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        </cfquery>
```

Comment: what does actUpdateClIndivNote.cfm look like?

Comment: inspect the request itself in browser console network tab to see if what is sent is what you expect. IN cfm file do a `cfdump` of `form` and abort then inspect that in body of request response

Comment: Duncan; I added the actUpdateClIndivNote.cfm code.
charlietfl; I know the code works.  I ran it in a browser passing the params in the url and it updated correctly with no errors.

Comment: yes, it works if you pass the params in the url, as you directly refer to them in the url scope. Your AJAX request uses a post, so they're in the form scope instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need

'&IndivNote' + thisindivnote
'&IndivNote=' + thisindivnote

Of note, I would `<cfparam>` your expected values to set defaults for debugging. Then you can take them away to see issues. You can also add dumps to dump the URL/Form scope and then just check those in the replay of your XHR request in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: That was it.  Sometimes we get soooo bogged down we can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: There is no magic in development unless it comes to one adobe's bugs. Those tend to act like magic.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this.  You're making a POST to actUpdateClIndivNote.cfm:

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
```

However that file expects values in the URL:

- url.IndivNote
- url.userid
- url.callListId

If you do as charlie suggests and dump out the FORM scope, you should see entries for IndivNote, userid and callListId.  If you dump out the URL scope, it should be empty (or at least not contain those values you're then trying to reference).

Either change your AJAX request from type = POST to type = GET.  Or change your CFM / CFC to expect values in the Form scope instead of the URL scope (i.e. `#form.IndivNote#` etc).

Comment: I changed url to form (good catch.  I should have seen that one).  But I still get the 500 error.  The error routine is not being hit.  Nor the success routine.